# How can I reference to an Algorithm employed in figure environment in latex? When I'm using \ref{} , latex does not know its associated label

Tags: floats, algorithms, ref

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{autart}    

\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}          


\begin{document}

\begin{figure} 
\label{Fig1}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
1: \textbf{for} each mode $i\hspace{0.08cm}\epsilon \hspace{0.08cm}\mathcal I$ \textbf{do}

2: \hspace{0.8cm}$\Omega_i^0=\mathcal{X}_i$

3: \textbf{end for}

4: \textbf{repeat}

5: \textbf{for} each mode $i\hspace{0.08cm}\epsilon \hspace{0.08cm}\mathcal I$ \textbf{do}
 \caption{My Pseudocode }
\end{algorithm}
\caption{My Figure Caption .}
\end{figure}



As Figure.~\ref{Fig1} mentions 


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\label` always has to come after (or in) `\caption` But why are you nesting algorithm inside figure?

Comment: The number gets assigned by the `\caption` command, so always put the `\label` command directly underneath the `\caption`.

Comment: Also: you have entered the pseudocode manually, with `\textbf` and `\hspace` commands, manual line numbers etc. There are also packages that help you format the pseudocode more easily, see for example https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms.

Comment: Thanks. I inserted the \label command directly underneath the \caption and it looks true now. Latex  knows its associated label now.

Answer (score 1):

You load the package `algpseudocode` anyway, so let's use it. See the [documentation of the package `algorithmicx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf) for details.

Side-note: For the 'is-element-of' relation, there is the TeX command `\in`. If you don't like the symbol, one can change it, but it is not advisable to use something like `\hspace{0.08cm}\epsilon \hspace{0.08cm}` instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
\For{each mode $i\in\mathcal I$}
\State $\Omega_i^0=\mathcal{X}_i$
\EndFor
\Repeat
  \For{each mode $i\in\mathcal I$}
  \EndFor
\Until{bored}
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{My Pseudocode }
\label{Fig1}
\end{algorithm}

See Algorithm~\ref{Fig1}. 

\end{document}
```

If you prefer to refer to the algorithm as a figure, I suggest to replace `algorithm` by `figure`, but not to nest them.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
\For{each mode $i\in\mathcal I$}
\State $\Omega_i^0=\mathcal{X}_i$
\EndFor
\Repeat
  \For{each mode $i\in\mathcal I$}
  \EndFor
\Until{bored}
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{My Pseudocode }
\label{Fig1}
\end{figure}

See Figure~\ref{Fig1}. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Both of your sugessions are intersting.